# Thrustmaster Steering wheel on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, controller

I’m using Ubuntu. I have issue with my steering wheel.
My steering wheel Thrustmaster F458 is detected as xbox gamepad in f.e. F1 22. All inputs are working and that wouldn’t be a problem, but because it is being detected as gamepad it has wide range of rotation where input is not detected. I checked raw inputs and it is detected normally, but because of being gamepad it is reduced and you need to make bigger rotation to start turning. I’ve installed Oversteer but it obviously didn’t help, any ideas what can I try?
Cheers!

Comment: Is your driver uptodate

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu? Perhaps  the issue does not exist in a later version.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS @DrMoishePippik

Comment: Pretty dumb question, but how to check if my driver is up to date? @Toto

Comment: @mmarusiak, No, *not* a bad question, and the Thrustmaster site only shows Windows drivers. Others have the issue, too: https://linustechtips.com/topic/576104-how-to-use-thrustmaster-ferrari-458-spyder-steering-wheel-on-pc/, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301506/thrustmaster-ferrari-gt-experience-wheel-on-ubuntu-20-04 . https://steamcommunity.com/app/270880/discussions/0/3085508296773389302/ ,